# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /category/5

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am a new developer working on a Sinatra/Ruby/ActiveRecord app.  I have established a 1:many (postgres) relationship between Category and Recipe.  When I try to list the recipes in a category I get the error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /category/5
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column recipes.category_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."category_id... ^ : SELECT 1 AS one FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."category_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
file: postgresql_adapter.rb location: prepare line: 637

app.rb

```
get('/category/:id') do
  @category = Category.find(params.fetch('id'))
  @recipes = @category.recipes
  erb(:category)
end
```

category.erb

```
<% if @recipes.any?() %>
  <% @recipes.each() do |recipe| %>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='/recipe/<%=recipe.id%>'> <%=recipe.recipe_name%></a></li>
    </ul>
  <%end%>
<%else %>
  <p>You have no recipes!</p>
<%end%>
```

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150930234556) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "cat_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image_name"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "alt"
    t.integer  "width"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
  end

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "ingredient_name"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "instructions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "instruction_name"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "recipe_name"
    t.string   "source"
    t.string   "servings"
    t.string   "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "cat_id"
  end
end
```

I have searched my project folders and cannot find category_id.  Don't know why it's looking for that, my field names are category.id and recipe.cat_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
@recipes = @category.recipes
```

suggests that you have

```
has_many :recipes
```

in your `Category` model. That `has_many` will be looking for a `category_id` column in your `recipes` table (i.e. a `category_id` attribute in your `Recipe` model). But you don't have a `recipes.category_id` column, you have a `recipes.cat_id` column:

```
create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
  #...
  t.integer  "cat_id"
end
```

I'd recommend renaming the `recipes.cat_id` column to `recipes.category_id` to match the conventions that Rails has a very strong preference for. If you can't rename the column then add a `:foreign_key` option to that `has_many` to tell `Category` how to resolve the relationship:

```
has_many :recipes, :foreign_key => :cat_id
```

Comment: Thank you mu!  I am no longer getting the error.  Still not getting the recipes to list on the view, but I will work on that!

Comment: Have you look at what is in `@recipes` without going through the ERB?